# Android: How to get the uploaded file URL in Google Drive

Tags: java, android, file-upload, google-drive-api

I can upload files to my Google Drive account but I need to get the URL (link) of the file to use it later?
example: https://docs.google.com/file/d/oB-xxxxxxxxxxx/edit

This is my method to upload file to Google Drive:

```
private void saveFileToDrive()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Create URI from real path
                String path;
                path = "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/a.png";
                mFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(path));

                ContentResolver cR = UploadActivity.this.getContentResolver();

                // File's binary content
                java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(mFileUri.getPath());
                FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(cR.getType(mFileUri), fileContent);

                showToast("Selected " + mFileUri.getPath() + "to upload");

                // File's meta data. 
                File body = new File();
                body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
                body.setMimeType(cR.getType(mFileUri));                 
                com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files f1 = mService.files();
                com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.Insert i1 = f1.insert(body, mediaContent);
                File file = i1.execute();

                if (file != null) 
                {
                    showToast("Uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
                }
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showToast("Transfer ERROR: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it, we just need to get the file ID and adding some string as in the following:

```
private void saveFileToDrive()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String ImageLink = null;

                // Create URI from real path
                String path;
                path = "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/b.mov";
                mFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(path));

                ContentResolver cR = UploadActivity.this.getContentResolver();

                // File's binary content
                java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(mFileUri.getPath());
                FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(cR.getType(mFileUri), fileContent);

                showToast("Selected " + mFileUri.getPath() + " to upload");

                // File's meta data. 
                File body = new File();
                body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
                body.setMimeType(cR.getType(mFileUri));                 
                com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files f1 = mService.files();
                com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.Insert i1 = f1.insert(body, mediaContent);
                File file = i1.execute();

                if (file != null) 
                {
                    showToast("Uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
                }

                if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0)
                {
                   ImageLink = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=" + file.getId() +"&authuser=0";
                   System.out.println("ImageLink:  " + ImageLink);

                }



            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showToast("Transfer ERROR: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```